# What the most optimal structure to use if i have to iterate and compare?

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary

I am developing a .NET 4.0 C# console application.

My understanding is that Dictionaries are implemented internally using hash tables and as such as really fast if they are accessed by their keys.

I have a situation where I need to keep track of a list of objects by keys and need to iterate thru them often, so would like to find the optimal implementation.   I can also split up the objects into multiple dictionaries using the same index but having simple integers for example as the Value.   I cannot make the Values Indexes as they are not unique.

Here's basically what I'm trying to do:

```
        Dictionary<int, myCustomObject> items;
        private void funciton1(int _i)  // Gets called MANY MANY times a second!
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair <int, myCustomObject> pair in items)
            {
                if ((pair.Value.a == "hello") && (pair.Value.b > _i) {
                    doSomething(pair.Key);
                }
            }
        }
```

So the question is:  Is there something faster than Dictionaries I should be using?  Or some trick to iterate faster?

Adding clarification.    Analogy:  If this were a stock trading platform:
My routine would get called frequently and with each call, I'd have to check if any of my orders meet a certain criteria based on the market (variable passed in).  More specifically, with each call, I'd have to do something like:  If my order is a Buy, check if the price is greater than... if it is a sell....

Comment: If you're never acessing by key, a list of tuples would make more sense (not saying its necessarily more performant, you'd have to benchmark).

Comment: Looking at your code, I don't think your question matches your problem...  What exactly are you trying to do?  Why do you feel the need to iterate through the entire hash table "many many" times per second and compare two properties from the value together?  Also, when you say that you cannot make the values indexes, are you referring to property b of the value object?

Comment: Assuming you do have a good reason to do frequent polling, your code is already fast enough - the iterator is supposedly giving you linear time complexity for one scan. However, as Taegost mentioned, the frequent polling is questionable. Can you use event&listener between your custom object and the 'doSomething'?

Comment: If you are looking for search performance, use a SortedList. If you are looking for both insert and search performance, use a dictionnary. See this link [benchmark](http://blog.bodurov.com/Performance-SortedList-SortedDictionary-Dictionary-Hashtable/)

Comment: Added clarification / reasoning with an analogy.  Yes... I need to 'add' so cannot use static Sorted List.   Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to find all of the items matching a given key, you're trying to find all of the items with an int value greater than a provided value.  You aren't going to get that out of a hash based set.  It's very good at finding the items *exactly matching a key*, but that's not what you're trying to do.

To find all of the value greater than a given value what you really want is a sorted collection that you can do a binary search on to quickly find the lower bound and then easily traverse the collection up to find all of the larger items.

So to start with you'll need a comparer that can compare pairs of your custom object and an int based on the `b` value of your custom object:

```
public class MyPairedObjectComparer : IComparer<KeyValuePair<myCustomObject, int>>
{
    public int Compare(KeyValuePair<myCustomObject, int> x,
        KeyValuePair<myCustomObject, int> y)
    {
        if (x.Key == null && y.Key == null)
            return 0;
        else if (x.Key == null)
            return -1;
        else if (y.Key == null)
            return 1;
        else
            return x.Key.b.CompareTo(y.Key.b);
    }

    private static MyPairedObjectComparer instance = new MyPairedObjectComparer();
    public static MyPairedObjectComparer Default { get { return instance; } }
}
```

Then your actual function can just call `BinarySearch` on a `List` using the custom comparer, and then iterate the list to get all items at or above that index:

```
List<KeyValuePair<myCustomObject, int>> list =
    new List<KeyValuePair<myCustomObject, int>>();
//note make sure list is sorted when modified with 
//list.Sort(MyPairedObjectComparer.Default);
private void funciton1(int _i)  // Gets called MANY MANY times a second!
{
    var objectToSearchWith = new myCustomObject()
    {
        b = _i + 1,
    };
    var pair = new KeyValuePair<myCustomObject, int>(objectToSearchWith, 0);
    var index = list.BinarySearch(pair, MyPairedObjectComparer.Default);
    if (index < 0)
        index = ~index;
    for (int i = index; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        doSomething(list[i].Value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Servy.  While I understand your written answer, your code is leaving me baffled.    I have no issue creating a seperate list but need to keep track of the associated Key. In other words, I have a list of objects which are keyed and can, for the sake of optimization, create a separate list, extracting the one integer i need to compare... to a second list but need to keep track of the associated Key... which I will not have with a simple list ?   I will look at your code more to see if I can understand it.

Comment: @EdLandau That's why it's a list of `KeyValuePair` objects, and not just a list of ints, and why it needs a custom comparer.

Answer (score 0):

As servy said use binary search algorithm.

To explain binary search imagine you are looking for the word "hello" in a big dictionary book.

If you navigate to the middle of the book you will reach words starting with M.
Now is H less or greater than M? Navigate to the middle page again you hit 'F'. Continue the binary search until you find Hello.

IF your list is a million elements you will only loop a max of 20 times to find the word 'Hello'. This is better than looping a million times.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? I tried to make this as a comment but unfortunately I do not have enough reputation for that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad English.

If you need a really fast code, should take into account the processor cache.
Google 'cache conscious hot cold' for more info.

As you iterate over all elements of a collection, you do not get any benefit from the dictionary. KeyValuePair, contains three values: a, b and key is loaded into the cache at each loop iteration. Meanwhile, unless the first condition operator 'if' is false, then the second value is not needed, as well as the key.

Therefore, the dictionary can be replaced by lists or arrays. In order to ensure an effective load into the processor cache, we need two (or three) of the list: List  a, List  b , and maybe List  key.
For what? The data is loading into the processor cache by parts. In the case of KeyValuePair, the cache will get a small number of such pairs, as each has a fairly big size. Meanwhile, if value b <= _i, then a string 'a' should never be loaded into the cache. That's why we made a two or three lists: hot and cold, one is always load into the cache, and others only when necessary.

The next question is: what range ​​are the keys? If they are continuous range of integers, then we do not need the third list key. List index may play its role.

```
List<string> a = ...
List<int> b =    ...
List<int> key =  ...

static void funciton1(int _i)  // Gets called MANY MANY times a second!
{
    for (int i = 0; i < b.Count; i++)
    {
        if (b[i] > _i) // hot
        {
            if (a[i] == "hello") // cold
            {
                doSomething(key[i]); // cold
                // or maybe
                doSomething(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although perhaps data size is small and easy fit to the cache. Consequently, separation by hot and cold data is not necessary.

Comment: Cache optimized linear search will hardly beat binary search in any real-world dataset.

Comment: @Mephy For binary search the data firstly must to be sorted. It's time-consuming. Moreover, nothing prevents combine cache conscious and binary search.

Comment: Sorting the data only becomes an expensive cost if the data is manipulated frequently, rather than being primarily searched on, which appears to be the case.

Comment: @Servy There is Cache-Conscious Binary Search algorithm. It's more effective than simple binary search.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at nosql database engines like redis. It is a key value database that stays in memory and will even allow you to set how long to persist the key value pair.